# Create 2 relationships with one match query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I wanted to turn:

```
MATCH (a:link)
  MATCH (b:node {id:a.us_node_id})
    CREATE (a)-[r:ds_link]->(b)
MATCH (a:link)
  MATCH (b:node {id:a.us_node_id})
    CREATE (b)-[r:us_node]->(a)
```

into something like:

```
MATCH (a:link)
  MATCH (b:node {id:a.us_node_id})
    CREATE (a)-[r:ds_link]->(b),
    CREATE (b)-[r:us_node]->(a)
```

Is this doable? Because the 2nd looks a lot neater than the 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and we would encourage the second approach since it's more concise (you usually don't need to re-MATCH to nodes that are already in scope).

You're likely getting a syntax error, though, so either use one CREATE with comma-separated patterns, or two CREATEs without any comma between them.

Like so:

```
MATCH (a:link)
  MATCH (b:node {id:a.us_node_id})
    CREATE (b)-[:ds_link]->(a),
           (a)-[:us_node]->(b)
```